# Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Я пытаюсь получить данные из Cat API https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds/ но получаю исключение Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
Никак не могу найти в каком месте я ошибся

CatList class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/catData.dart';

class CatList extends StatelessWidget {
  CatList({Key key, List<CatData> catList})
      : _catList = catList,
        super(key: key);
  final List<CatData> _catList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _catList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  _catList[index].lifeSpan,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

model class CatData

```
class CatData {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String cfaUrl;
  final String temperament;
  final String origin;
  final String countryCodes;
  final String countryCode;
  final String description;
  final String lifeSpan;
  final String childFriendly;

  CatData(
      this.id,
      this.name,
      this.cfaUrl,
      this.temperament,
      this.origin,
      this.countryCodes,
      this.countryCode,
      this.description,
      this.lifeSpan,
      this.childFriendly);

  CatData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'],
        cfaUrl = json['cfa_url'],
        temperament = json['temperament'],
        origin = json['origin'],
        countryCodes = json['country_codes'],
        countryCode = json['country_code'],
        description = json['description'],
        lifeSpan = json['life_span'],
        childFriendly = json['child_friendly'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'cfa_url': cfaUrl,
        'temperament': temperament,
        'origin': origin,
        'country_codes': countryCodes,
        'country_code': countryCode,
        'description': description,
        'life_span': lifeSpan,
        'child_friendly': childFriendly,
      };
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'widgets/catList.dart';
import 'models/catData.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AnimalsListScreen());
}

Future<List<CatData>> fetchCats(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds/');
  return compute(parseCat, response.body);
}

List<CatData> parseCat(responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody) as List;
  return parsed.map<CatData>((json) => CatData.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class AnimalsListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimalListScreenState createState() => _AnimalListScreenState();
}

class _AnimalListScreenState extends State<AnimalsListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Practice 3'),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<List<CatData>>(
              future: fetchCats(http.Client()),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? CatList(
                        catList: snapshot.data,
                      )
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну например в ответе:

```
"child_friendly":3 // число
```

А у Вас:

```
final String childFriendly; // строка
```

Максимально простой вариант - прогоните данные в [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) и сравните результат со своим.